# Need assistance to understand a piece of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having difficulties to understand the code below taken from this page http://trevordavis.net/play/jquery-one-page-nav/ (tutorial for one page websites). Especially the .do and the Lorem ispum text in the middle of the code and also the reference to section-4. Could you shade some light on that? Many thanks

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.nav.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav').onePageNav();

  $('.do').click(function(e) {
    $('#section-4').append('<p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: `$('.do')` is a selector, so it looks for elements with a class of `do`, and then the `$('#section-4').append()` adds a paragraph to the element with `id="section-4"`. Note, you should only ever have **one** element with a unique `id` value per page, but you can have multiple elements grouped by `class`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the ".click" function is not recommended anymore and you should use ".on('click', function(){})" instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.do').click(function(e) {
    $('#section-4').append('<p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

This is creating a click event handler on all elements with the class of do. When the element is clicked, a paragraph with the Lorem ipsum text will be added to the element with id section-4.